# Is there a python library for classifying whether an image contains handwritten text?

Tags: library, python, image-processing, computer-vision, neural-network

I don't require what is written inside that image, i just want to know whether an image has any handwritten text.

Comment: Does it need to distinguish hand written text from script-fonts like Lucida, Ministry, Nina or Penultimate?

Comment: Relevant papers are https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6779466, https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Automatic-Discrimination-between-Printed-and-Text-Silva-Conci/4db4eeb125635d9f9ac7c405b04635abf4c09f98, and https://www.researchgate.net/publication/45718434_Discrimination_between_Printed_and_Handwritten_Text_in_Documents

Comment: @ThomasWeller No it doesn't need to distinguish between any fonts